# Better way to modify middle character of string?

Tags: php, string, replace, cpu-word

I want to be able to put an HTML tag around the left-middle character of a word string. It sounds simple enough, but I'm not sure how to account for all of the most common words.

Here is the PHP I have as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<?php
    $word = 'WONDERLAND';
    $wlen = strlen($word);
    $lPad = floor($wlen/2)+1;
    $rPad = ceil($wlen/2);
    $left = substr($word, 0, -$lPad);
    $middle = substr($word, -$lPad, 1);
    $right = substr($word, -$rPad, $lPad);
    echo $left.$middle.$right;
?>
```

The output:

```
WONDERLAND
```

or

```
$left(WOND).$middle(E).$right(RLAND)
```

I would like to be able to make the middle character (if an even-character word, the left-most of the two middle characters) bold with a `<b>` tag and can do so with this word. I run into problems when I try other words that are smaller. Will I have to create `if` statements for every word length? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your "output" isn't clear as to the expected result. And I assume by "middle character" in a word with an even char count, you would mean the middle two "ER" ?

Comment: Updated for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: what output would you expect when given a one lettered word?

Comment: I apologize. The R would find itself on the right side.

Comment: I tried running your script and it seems to be working fine.  It's just not clear what output you want for one and two-lettered words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to make the middle character (**if an
>   even-character word, the left-most of the two middle characters**) bold
>   with a  tag and can do so with this word. I run into problems when
>   I try other words that are smaller. Will I have to create if
>   statements for every word length? Or is there a better way to do it?

Based on your question, shouldn't this should be more appropriate:

```
$aWord[] = 'A';
$aWord[] = 'AB';
$aWord[] = 'ABC';
$aWord[] = 'ABCD';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDE';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDEF';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDEFG';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDEFGH';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDEFGHI';
$aWord[] = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';

foreach ($aWord AS $nPos => $word)
{
    $wlen = strlen($word);
    $lPad = floor($wlen/2)+1;
    $rPad = ceil($wlen/2);
    $left = substr($word, 0, -$lPad);
    $middle = substr($word, -$lPad, 1); 
    $right = substr($word, $rPad, $lPad);
    echo "$left<b>$middle<b>$right\n";
}
```

output:

```
<b>A<b>
<b>A<b>B
A<b>B<b>C
A<b>B<b>CD
AB<b>C<b>DE
AB<b>C<b>DEF
ABC<b>D<b>EFG
ABC<b>D<b>EFGH
ABCD<b>E<b>FGHI
ABCD<b>E<b>FGHIJ
```

Comment: Yes, yes, it is. Thank you for bearing with me and setting me straight.